# How to only search keywords inside of the current/selective function?

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
def a():
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2[cursor location]

def b():
    var2 = 2
    var3 = 3
```

In vscode, if I want to search for `var2`, I can put my cursor on top of `var2` and vscode will highlight it for me. However, I want to only highlight `var2` inside of function `a`, so `var2` in `b` will not be highlighted. When click on "next match", I want it to cycle through only inside of function `a` too.

Searching in vscode also does it globally. Vim extension for vscode also does it globally.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using the Find widget and its `Find In Selection` option and selecting the code you want to restrict the search to.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it (at least on windows):

1. Click anywhere inside the function
2. Select the whole line with `Ctrl` + `L`
3. "Expand" that selection with `Alt` + `Shift` + `→`
4. Press `Ctrl` + `F` to pop up the find menu
5. Then press `Alt` + `L` to turn on "Find in Selection"
6. Start typing what you want to search
7. (Optionally) You can press `F3` to go to the next occurrence and `Shift` + `F3` to go to the previous occurrence

Of course, you can use the mouse where you can instead of some keyboard shortcuts.